# How to display data from model in td based off select list item in another td

Tags: javascript, c#, asp.net-mvc, razor

I have a separate TR and inside, a TD from the rest of my table. I have some data in my model that contains a list of strings, and also a list of IDs (not sure if I need the list of IDS for this) and I would like to display on the lower Tr's td a specific part of the list, based off of the selection of a SelectListItem in the table row's td above it.. i.e. If a user select's a list item of X, I want the TD below to display "X's help description" (which like I mentioned earlier, is being stored inside a list of strings in my model)

I am not sure if I should be doing this in Razor, Javascript, or something else. Can anyone give me some tips? Below is some code.

View:

```
 <div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-12" style="overflow-y:scroll">
        <table class="table table-striped table-hover table-bordered">
            <thead>
                <tr>
                    <th>Terminal</th>
                    <th>Command</th>
                    <th>Command Value</th>
                    <th> </th>
                </tr>
            </thead>
            <tbody>
                <tr>
                    <td>@Html.DropDownListFor(o => o.TerminalsDDL, Model.TerminalsDDL, new { id = "ddlTerminalID", @class = "form-control" })</td>
                    <td>@Html.DropDownListFor(o => o.TerminalCommandLookupsDDL, Model.TerminalCommandLookupsDDL, new {id = "ddlCommandValue", @class = "form-control" })</td>
                    <td>@Html.TextBoxFor(o => o.UserEnteredTerminalCommands, new { Class = "form-control", Id = "cmdValueValue"})</td>
                    <td> <input id="btnSaveTerminalCommand" type="button"  value="Insert" class="btn btn-primary" /> </td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td colspan="4" id="helpDescript">@Html.DisplayFor(model => model.HelpDescription)</td>
                </tr>
            </tbody>
        </table>
    </div>
</div>
```

VM:

```
 public TerminalCommandVM()
    {
        //Terminals Drop Down List
        TerminalsDDL = new List<SelectListItem>();

        //Terminal Commands Drop Down List
        TerminalCommandLookupsDDL = new List<SelectListItem>();

        //Terminal Command Values list
        TerminalCommandValues = new List<SelectListItem>();

    }

    public TerminalCommand TerminalCommand { get; set; }

    public List<TerminalCommand> TerminalCommands { get; set; }

    [Display(Name = "Terminal ID")]
    public List<SelectListItem> TerminalsDDL { get; set; }

    [Display(Name = "Command")]
    public List<SelectListItem> TerminalCommandLookupsDDL { get; set; }

    public List<SelectListItem> TerminalCommandValues { get; set; }

    public string UserEnteredTerminalCommands { get; set; }

    public List<string> HelpDescription { get; set; }

    public List<int> HelpDescriptionID { get; set; }
}
```

The DisplayFor I want populated is the one with the ID = "helpDescript", and the select list item that should dictate which help descript is displayed has the ID = "ddlCommandValue".

As of now, helpDescript is displaying the entire list (obviously).

If anyone needs any other code or more information, please let me know.

Comment: You want to display a description based on the dropdown value right?. You can achieve this by JQuery AJAX

Comment: @Golda, yes I do

Answer (score 0):

Try the following. In the dropdown change event call the action to display the value and in the success function display the value in label

```
$("#ddlCommandValue").change(function () {
    var obj = {
        valueToPass: $(this).val()
    };
    $.ajax({
        url: '/Home/GetValueToDisplayInlabel',
        contentType: 'application/json; charset=utf-8',
        type: 'POST',
        data: JSON.stringify(obj),
        cache: false,
        success: function (result) {
            $("#helpDescript").html(result);
        },
        error: function () {
            alert("Error");
        }
});
```